# How split dataset to non-iid form

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, tensorflow-federated

I have my own dataset containing 12 000 images from 3 classes, and I have 4 clients, I would like to create a non-iid dataset like the paper of McMahan,

I find this code which divide mnist examples into fragments. So how can I update this code knwing that I have 12 000 examples overall.

```
def mnist_noniid(dataset, num_users):
    """
    Sample non-I.I.D client data from MNIST dataset
    :param dataset:
    :param num_users:
    :return:
    """
    num_shards, num_imgs = 200, 300
    idx_shard = [i for i in range(num_shards)]
    dict_users = {i: np.array([], dtype='int64') for i in range(num_users)}
    idxs = np.arange(num_shards*num_imgs)
    labels = dataset.train_labels.numpy()
    print(labels)
    # sort labels
    idxs_labels = np.vstack((idxs, labels))
    idxs_labels = idxs_labels[:,idxs_labels[1,:].argsort()]
    idxs = idxs_labels[0,:]

    # divide and assign
    for i in range(num_users):
        rand_set = set(np.random.choice(idx_shard, 2, replace=False))
        idx_shard = list(set(idx_shard) - rand_set)
        for rand in rand_set:
            dict_users[i] = np.concatenate((dict_users[i], idxs[rand*num_imgs:(rand+1)*num_imgs]), axis=0)
    return dict_users
```